# email client failing to add second recipient

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

I am currently working on an emailspammer which is on github: ([Spammer](https://github.com/Curioo/emailpyspam)) And the code basically works, but the program wont add another recipient. When checking the recipients, it shows them as added, but the emails dont get delivered. Im not getting errors either. Any help? all the code is on github, it is too much to add into this question. (sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

hi can you give permission to push to your repository. `github_username = shreyanshu7101904` actually there is problem in server.send_message method parameter to_addr should be list not string.

Comment: check this PR [Link] (https://github.com/Curioo/emailpyspam/pull/1) @Curio